# Uniformly continuous function with unbounded variation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

It is known that if $f(x):R\to R$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$, then it has bouded variation on $[a,b]$. Is it also true for uniformly continuous functions? And if not then what is an example?

Comment: Wikipedia gives the standard example $f(x) = x \sin (1/x)$ extended by continuity on $[0,2/ \pi]$.

Comment: For an extreme example, take your favorite pathological continuous function on a compact interval, say a nowhere differentiable continuous function. (If you want an example that's uniformly continuous on the entire real line, then extend the function to be constant outside the interval.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take $f(x)=x$, it is uniformly continuous but does not have bounded variation over $\mathbb{R}$

Even you can find uniformly continuous functions without bounded variation in an interval say $[0,1]$.

You can make such a function by joining discrete line segments.
Consider any continuous function passing through the points $(1/2n,1/n)$ and $(1/(2n+1),0)$, this is composed of linear segments. It must have infinite variation because its variation is the summation of the harmonic series which diverges.